# Getting a dictionary item from a list in a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

Suppose I have a dictionary, that then has a list of dictionaries within it:

```
cslfJson = {'displayFieldName': 'CSLF_ID',
            'features': [{'attributes': {'OBJECTID': '13000', 'CSLF_ID': '08123', 'Area_SF': '5431'},
                         {'attributes': {'OBJECTID': '12000', 'CSLF_ID': '08137', 'Area_SF': '2111'}}]}
```

How would I call `OBJECTID` in a `print` statement? WIle I can print something like this

```
print(cslfJson['features'][1]['attributes']['OBJECTID'])
```

I am trying to print both OBJECTID's like this:

```
for index in cslfJson['features']: 
    print(cslfJson['features'][index]['attributes']['OBJECTID'])
```

The above throws a `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict` error, so I am confused on the correct syntax.

Comment: How do you access elements of a list? It doesn't matter whether this list is itself an element of a dictionary...

Comment: There are two OBJECTID's, What precisely are you trying to print?

Comment: Editing. The goal would be to print both OBJECTID's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are iterating over the *contents* of the list, not the indices, so `index` is itself the dictionary.  There are several options to iterate over the indices, or you could use the dictionary that you're being given instead:

```
for subdictionary in cslfJson['features']: 
    print(subdictionary['attributes']['OBJECTID'])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print(*x['attributes']['OBJECTID'] for x in cslfJson['features'])
```